# Bash script to remove dot end of each line

Tags: bash

Unix command to remove dot at end of each line in file.

Sample rec in file

```
11234567                 0.
23456789              5569.
34567810                 1.
10162056                 0.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\.$//' yourfile
```

- Escape the special character `.` using `\`.
- Put an achor `$` to only remove it from the end.
- To make infile changes use `-i` option of `sed`.

Comment: +1; OSX users: use `-i ''` to modify the input file in place (just `-i` won't work).

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 for always adding value to the answers!

Answer (score 2):

```
 sed -e 's/\.$//'
```

done. (padding to make answer long enough. grumble)

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest `[.]` instead of `\.` -- a character longer, but much less ambiguous (as backslashes can be eaten, need to be escaped, etc. depending on context).

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/\.$//' /path/to/file
```

This will match a literal period that is anchored to the end of the line, and replace it with nothing.  The <kbd>-i</kbd> tells sed to make the change inline.

Comment: s/inline/inplace/ (i.o.w. it replaces the source file)